# MySQL select only unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

Clients:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|   CLIENT_ID  |    LABEL    |
+--------------+-------------+
|          123 |      label1 |
+--------------+-------------+
|          123 |      label3 |
+--------------+-------------+
|          456 |      label1 |
+--------------+-------------+
|          789 |      label2 |
+--------------+-------------+
|          987 |      label2 |
+--------------+-------------+
|          987 |      label4 |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Managers:

```
+----+--------------+
| ID |   CLIENT_ID  |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |          123 |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |          456 |
+----+--------------+
|  2 |          456 |
+----+--------------+
|  3 |          789 |
+----+--------------+
|  3 |          987 |
+----+--------------+
|  4 |          789 |
+----+--------------+
```

I need to select ID from Managers which have only clients with labels "label1" or "label2" and do not have clients with other labels.
The resulting output should be like 2 and 4.

I tried to do as

```
select m.id
from managers m
    join clients c on m.client_id = c.client_id
where c.label in ('label1', 'label2');
```

but it returns all ids.

Comment: You can do a GROUP BY, and use HAVING to make sure there no other labels. Or do NOT EXISTS.

Comment: you're using alias s in from and m in select and join condition?

Comment: Please check as per your question answer should be 2, 3 and 4 bcz for 3 client_id is 789 and 987  belongs to label 2 and label 4.

Comment: No, I need to have only those managers who have clients with label1 or label2 and do not have clients with other labels. If the have clients with other labels they should not apper in the result

Answer (score 0):

Close.  Just add aggregation:

```
select m.id
from managers s join
     clients c
     on m.client_id = c.client_id
where c.label in ('label1', 'label2')
group by m.id
having count(distinct c.label) = 2;
```

If you want *only* clients with these two labels, then use:

```
select m.id
from managers s join
     clients c
     on m.client_id = c.client_id
group by m.id
having count(distinct c.label) = 2;

select m.id
from managers s join
     clients c
     on m.client_id = c.client_id
group by m.id
having count(distinct case when c.label in ('label1', 'label2') then c.label end) = 2 and
       count(distinct c.label) = 2;
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
having sum(c.label = 'label1') > 0 and
       sum(c.label = 'label2') > 0 and
       sum(c.label not in ('label1', 'label2')) = 0;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this query returns also returns managers with other labels. For example manager has client with label1 and other client with label3.

Comment: @fustacre . . . I misunderstood the question, but the same idea holds:  you can adjust the `having` clause to do what you want (and eliminate the `where`).

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` as follows:

```
select m.id
from managers m
    join clients c on m.client_id = c.client_id
where c.label in ('label1', 'label2')
group by m.id
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try  `group by` and `having` statement here to get unique records

```
 SELECT ID FROM `Clients` c 
  left join Managers m on (c.client_id = m.CLIENT_ID) 
  where LABEL in ('label1', 'label2') 
  group by ID having count(*) = 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to get the number of occurrences where client labels associated with a particular manager are valid:

```
with r as (select m.id id, sum(c.label in ('label1', 'label2')) c1, count(*) c2 
           from managers m join clients c on m.client_id = c.client_id group by m.id)
select id from r where c1 = c2;
```

Output:

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables, group by manager and use conditional aggregation for your conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM managers m INNER JOIN clients c 
ON m.client_id = c.client_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING MAX(c.label IN ('label1', 'label2')) = 1
   AND MAX(c.label NOT IN ('label1', 'label2')) = 0
```

This will also work if a client has both labels `'label1'` and `'label2'` and may be extended to more labels.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=63d1c03f7cf925a2c91009d83ebb369c).
Results:

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |